# Error, couldn't create file .. File name too long

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filenames

How can I increase the maximum length of a filename in linux?

I'm trying to download a torrent file, and apparently because it's `Cyrillic`, the file name hit's the limit.

```
error, couldn't create file "Как это сделано/128 (Литье автомобильных деталей с помощью воска; Лодка из стекловолокна; Сушильная машина; Лампочка высокой интенсивности; Тележка для покупок).avi":  File name too long
```

getconf -a | grep -i name

```
NAME_MAX                           255
_POSIX_NAME_MAX                    255
LOGNAME_MAX                        256
TTY_NAME_MAX                       32
TZNAME_MAX                         6
_POSIX_TZNAME_MAX                  6
CHARCLASS_NAME_MAX                 2048
HOST_NAME_MAX                      64
LOGIN_NAME_MAX                     256
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is in the filesystem. A file name on ext4 can only be 255 bytes long.
Your file name is 296 characters an therefore 296 bytes.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/166764/how-long-can-file-names-be

Comment: That's a good comment, but not an answer - the problem still isn't solved. Also, instead of posting bare links, it's preferred to include essential parts of the linked article (as a quote or rephrased) followed by a link. If the link ever goes down, your answer will still be useful.